# Adding text to jTextarea in jTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

I have a desktop program with 3 tabs i'm building in netbeans. There is 1 text input field below the three tabs. each tab has a jtextarea component. When i type in the text input field and hit enter i want it to add that text to the textarea contained by the currently selected tab.

I've been playing around with

```
jTabbedPane1.getSelectedIndex()

jTabbedPane1.getTabComponentAt()
```

How can i use the index to reference it back to the textarea associated with that tab?

Big java noob here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use an array of `JTextArea` components corresponding to the order that they appear on the `JTabbedPane`.

```
JTextArea[] textArea = new JTextArea[3];
// assign textAreas...
```

You could then set the text using the appropriate index:

```
int index = jTabbedPane1.getSelectedIndex();
textArea[index].setText(myField.getText());
```